# How launch bluecove programmatically

Tags: java, bluetooth, bluecove

I'm trying to lunch bluetooth stack manually(after closing bluetooh stack).

I look after [BlueCoveImpl.java](http://bluecove.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/bluecove/src/main/java/com/intel/bluetooth/BlueCoveImpl.java) and find out that bluetooth stack initialized in

```
private BluetoothStack detectStack()
```

method, which I trying to call by calling

```
BlueCoveImpl.instance().getBluetoothStack();
```

but exception occures:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Illegal use of the JSR-82 API
    at com.intel.bluetooth.Utils.isLegalAPICall(Utils.java:296)
    at com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl.getBluetoothStack(BlueCoveImpl.java:1023)
```

I also tried
            BlueCoveImpl.instance();
            BlueCoveImpl.getThreadBluetoothStackID();

but it made no effect.

How can I launch BlueCove?

Comment: To lunch it, cook it until it's soft enough to chew ;) (You meant "launch", unfortunately I can't help you with that.)

Comment: The persnickety "a" was added to "lunch" to "launch" it.

Answer (score 0):

The method

```
getBluetoothStack()
```

does some sort of security check by calling

```
Utils.isLegalAPICall
```

http://bluecove.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/bluecove/src/main/java/com/intel/bluetooth/Utils.java

This method checks if the call is done from a class out of these packages

1. javax.bluetooth.
2. getPackage(MicroeditionConnector.class.getName())

otherwise it throws

```
Error("Illegal use of the JSR-82 API")
```

I think that calling

```
LocalDevice.getLocalDevice()
```

http://bluecove.org/bluecove/apidocs/javax/bluetooth/LocalDevice.html#getLocalDevice()

will initialize the stack as needed. See https://code.google.com/p/bluecove/wiki/stacks for more information about how Bluecove will determine the correct stack and how you can do some configuration using the "bluecove.stack" system property.